# Resume installation/download after saving state of VM

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox as a VM and I was wondering the following.

If I am doing an installation of some sort (lets say. windows updates) and it seems to take longer than I want... If I were to save my VM to disk, and resume it later, would it continue to install without a problem?

I could understand that it would not resume a download because the internet connection is temporarily gone upon restoring, which is the same as unplugging a cable temporarily while you download. But what about installations?

So: Can you save/resume during an installation and expect the installation to be succesful afterwards?

Comment: if it were suspended, yes, if you shutdown the virtual machine thats just like shutting a real machine off

Comment: @Ramhound I am talking about using the "save state and power off" feature. Not the suspend feature in windows.

Comment: Even if it does work, this sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Yeah, I share that feeling, which is why I'm asking the question. It wil lbe for those "last resort" cases where waiting is worse than doing this. But at least I need to know if its possible to do this. Theoretically speaking it should be possible, but I'm just not sure. I couldn't find anything on the internet about what happens, so I posted this question in case someone actually tried it and can tell me for sure.

Comment: If you suspend a VM (suspend in VMWare is analogous to Save State in vBox), the RAM is saved to disk and will resume from where it was when you saved the state. The risk is that if the VM can't resume, it will have to boot from cold which can leave the install in an unknown state. In essence, you can suspend and resume, and assuming nothing goes wrong when resuming, the install will be fine. It's not a good idea to do this frequently, but it did save an MSSQL installation when the power went out...